# Aumentar tonalidade da cor

Tags: javascript, hexadecimal

Tenho por exemplo a seguinte cor em hex `#FAC328` e gostaria, via código, de aumentar sua tonalidade para mais 10% ficando desta maneira

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível fazer isso via javascript?

Comment: Meu aumento de 20% foi de `#E1AF24` para `#FFD22B`, como você fez a conta capa esse aumento?

Comment: Não seria mais fácil trabalhar com cores RGB e converter depois para hexadecimal, sendo assim mais facil calcular as tonalidades?

Comment: Leonardo me desculpa, mais na verdade é 10% vo editar rs

Comment: @VictorLaio já tentei mas não obtive sucesso via rgb

Answer (score 2):

Montei essa função que pega o HEX converte em DEC calcula o ganho e converte novamente em HEX

`hex` -> sem o `#`

`ganho` -> percentual de 0 a 100

o retorno você pode editar de acordo com a necessidade.

```js
function ganho(hex, ganho) {
 var r = Number.parseInt(Number.parseInt(hex.substring(0,2), 16) * ((ganho / 100) + 1)).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
 var g = Number.parseInt(Number.parseInt(hex.substring(2,4), 16) * ((ganho / 100) + 1)).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
 var b = Number.parseInt(Number.parseInt(hex.substring(4,6), 16) * ((ganho / 100) + 1)).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');

 return r + g + b;
}

console.log(ganho('101010', 10));
```

Comment: Já consegui entender a logica, obrigado, seu code da um retorno diferente do resultado esperado, mas consegui resolver seguindo o post que o Victor passou, de qualquer forma é a mesma logica, obrigado pela ajuda :D

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando o filtro `brightness` eu obtive o seguinte resultado.

```js
const dark = document.getElementById("dark");

dark.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let div = document.createElement("div");

  div.style.filter = "brightness(95%)";
  document.body.append(div);
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #FAC328;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #E1AF24;
}

button {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>#FAC328</div>
<div>#E1AF24</div>
<button id="dark">GENERATE</button>
```

> O valor base de 100% representa a cor atual do elemento.

Comment: boa solução, porém é possível eu conseguir pegar o resultado da cor gerada? pois no meu caso eu preciso descobrir a cor hexadecimal.

Comment: Eu procurei por uma solução e acredito que está é o exatamente o que está procurando: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560248/programmatically-lighten-or-darken-a-hex-color-or-rgb-and-blend-colors

Comment: lá tem algumas idéias sim, consegui resolve obrigado!